# SQL query to return a value based on holding a number of values in other corresponding columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the table below I am trying to run a query that returns a GroupId that has a number of corresponding `NodeIds`. For example if I have the `nodeIDs` 595,644,659 then `GroupId 2` would be returned but not 3, seen as thought 3 corresponds to `644` and `595` but `not 659`. I don't know would I have to do some kind of join ?
Wasn't too sure on how best to word the title, Thanks for any help.

```
GroupSchema_Id  GroupId ISchemeID   NodeId
1                     2 NULL            595
2                     2 NULL            644
3                     2 NULL            659
4                     2 NULL            662
5                     2 NULL            592
6                     2 NULL            626
7                     2 NULL            595
8                     3 NULL            644
9                     3 NULL            595
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `join`.  You can do what you want with `group by`:

```
select groupId
from t
where nodeId in (595, 644, 659)
group by groupId
having count(distinct nodeId) = 3;
```

Comment: Since it appears that nodes can be in a group twice (595 in group 2) I suspect that you should use `count(distinct nodeId)` rather than just `count(*)`.

Comment: @shawnt00 You are right, I updated, I did a quick check first and didnt saw any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Depending if the NodeID are unique for each group.

```
SELECT GroupId 
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY GroupID
HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN NodeID IN (595,644,659) 
                      THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END) = 3
```